# How to run IOTA Light Wallet behind proxy on Windows?

Tags: wallet, proxy, windows

If I start IOTA Wallet on windows with proxy configuration I get a lot of Java Script Errors. Is it possible to run the Wallet behind a Web Proxy? Windows Proxy Settings are configured, but still no connection possible.

Connection to Full Node is possible. "Edit Node Configuration" is not working. So I think it's a UI Library Proxy Issue.

It's a Squid Proxy. ACL SafePorts 21 70 80 210 280 443 488 563 591 631 777 901 1025-65535 ACL SSL Ports 8443 32400

Comment: ***How*** is your proxy configured? Otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: Proxy is configured in System Settings / Java / CMD. I think IOTA Wallet uses node.js and node.js doesn't recognize proxy settings. I've tried it over wpad.dat or with direct url http://proxy:port. All Windows Applications are working except IOTA Wallet which tries to connect directly to the internet. Connection to Node is working, but I can't edit Node Configuration and I don't have a node list if I click on "Edit Node Configuration"

Comment: That only explains the tools not the settings of your proxy.

Comment: It's a Squid Proxy.
ACL SafePorts 21 70 80 210 280 443 488 563 591 631 777 901 1025-65535
ACL SSLPorts 8443 32400

Comment: I'm also interested how to run the iota wallet behind a proxy. Can this be configured somehow?

Comment: I don't no yet. Still no solution